# Emacs Lisp print output

Tags: emacs, lisp, buffer, elisp, read-eval-print-loop

I ran the following code to print 15 sequential values of `i` both in the scratch buffer and the ielm repl:

```
    (defvar i 0)
    (while (< i 15)
       (print i)
       (setq i (+ i 1)))`
```

What I noticed in both the scratch buffer and the repl, is that they both only show the resulting value of the sexp. The printed values of `i` are then sent to the `Messages` buffer.

1. At least for the repl, how can I get the values of `i` printed in the repl?
2. If you have other solutions that have worked well for you, please let me know!

Note that I use emacs 24.3 through the terminal and Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. Thanks for all the help!

Additionally, From the documentation of `print` we have:

```
print is a built-in function in `C source code'.

(print OBJECT &optional PRINTCHARFUN)

Output the printed representation of OBJECT, with newlines around it.
Quoting characters are printed when needed to make output that `read'
can handle, whenever this is possible.  For complex objects, the behavior
is controlled by `print-level' and `print-length', which see.

OBJECT is any of the Lisp data types: a number, a string, a symbol,
a list, a buffer, a window, a frame, etc.

A printed representation of an object is text which describes that object.

Optional argument PRINTCHARFUN is the output stream, which can be one
of these:

   - a buffer, in which case output is inserted into that buffer at point;
   - a marker, in which case output is inserted at marker's position;
   - a function, in which case that function is called once for each
     character of OBJECT's printed representation;
   - a symbol, in which case that symbol's function definition is called; or
   - t, in which case the output is displayed in the echo area.

If PRINTCHARFUN is omitted, the value of `standard-output' (which see)
is used instead.
```

1. As I am new to practical aspects of lisp, how do I print to a different buffer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a tiny extension to Emacs Lisp `format` I've written to perform similar to Common Lisp `format`, but using `%` as the control character:

http://code.google.com/p/formatting-el/source/browse/trunk/formatting.el

So, for example, if you wanted to print a list of numbers with linebreaks into a string, you'd do it like so:

```
(cl-format "%{%s%^\n%}" (cl-loop for i from 0 below 10 collect i))
"0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9"
```

Another way to achieve this would be to use something like this:

```
(mapconcat #'number-to-string (cl-loop for i from 0 below 10 collect i) "\n")
"0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9"
```

Comment: Can't I load common-lisp features from my `.emacs` file?

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus I'm not quite sure what are you asking about... Common Lisp is a separate programming language, however, there is a package `cl` in Emacs Lisp, which provides functions similar to the ones found in its prototype. However, this package doesn't have an analogue to `format` from Common Lisp, my `cl-format` function is an attempt to compensate for that omission.

Comment: That was what I was asking about. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `with-output-to-string` if you really want:

```
(with-output-to-string
    (setq i 0)
    (while (< i 15)
      (princ i)
      (setq i (+ i 1))))
```

Comment: How would I print a newline between values of `i`? Is there some kind of format string?

Comment: If you want newline, use `print` instead of `princ`

Comment: If I do that then `with-output-to-string` gives me the values of `i` concatenated with newline characters `\n`

Comment: That's in ielm. It's different in *scratch*. But I don't see the issue. This is standard repl behavior.

Comment: scratch shows the messages buffer. Wouldn't it be nice to see the values you wish to print in the repl?  I am equating the lisp repl to what I am used to in python.

Comment: \*scratch\* doesn't show the messages buffer if you eval with C-j. Which you should always use in \*scratch\*, because that's what it's for.

Comment: Oddly, `C-j` is not evaluating sexp in the *scratch* buffer. It is bound to newline and indent when I checked the documentation.

Comment: `emacs -q` says otherwise. It's bound to `eval-print-last-sexp`. Maybe you've rebound it.

Comment: Should I globally set `C-j` like: `(global-set-key "\C-j" 'eval-print-last-sexp)` Or can you set this just for `(Emacs-Lisp)` mode? Which is better? What is the default mode for the *scratch* buffer? I keep trying to change it to `(Emacs-Lisp)` mode but it keeps opening up in `(Fundamental)` mode.

Comment: I think that you're loading some unnecessary customizations that are
overriding modes and shortcuts. You can always launch `emacs -q` from
the console to see what the default Emacs behavior is. Afterwards, if your
behavior is worse than the default one in your opinion, just locate the
place in `~/.emacs` that changes this behavior and turn it off.